# Airflow - whats happened to the AWS_GLUE_OPERATOR?

Tags: airflow, aws-glue

I was hoping to use Airflow to orchestrate and manage my AWS Glue Jobs, however the operator no longer appears in the GitHub repo.  Can anyone shed any light on this?

Additionally, i'm open to alternative orchestration tool suggestions.  I need to be able to Execute Glue jobs, whilst also interacting with other EC2's within my VPC.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a custom operator in airflow, which interacts with glue using boto3

Comment: Thanks, that is under consideration as I have actually built a small application that interacts with Glue using boto3, however I would clearly prefer to use one built by the community.

Answer (score 0):

The `AWSGlueJobOperator` is under construction and has good progress:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6007

Answer (score 0):

right now we have GlueJobOperator